# Solve for variable that is the upper limit of a summation

Tags: summation

It has been a really long time since I had to solve a problem like this and I was wondering if I could get some assistance with it.

$$x= \sum_{i=1}^{t} \frac{1}{i^c} \hspace{.25cm} \text{where } c \geq 0 $$

I am trying to solve for `t` for a given `x`.  If I recall correctly, one of the first steps is to write out the series like:

$$x = \frac{1}{1^c} + \frac{1}{2^c} +\frac{1}{3^c} + .... +  \frac{1}{t^c}$$

but I haven't a clue how to continue after that.

Comment: I guess you must go to the “numerical side”.

Comment: @FelixMarin I am not sure what you mean. What I am trying to do is write a program that calculates `t` without having to actually iterate and continuously check against `x`.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
x & \equiv \bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\sum_{i=1}^{t} \frac{1}{i^c}
\,\right\vert_{\ds{\ c \geq 0}}} =
\zeta\pars{c} + {t^{1 - c} \over 1 - c} +
c\int_{t}^{\infty}{\xi - \left\lfloor \xi\right\rfloor \over
\xi^{\,c\ +\ 1}}\,\dd\xi
\end{align}
which is a [Zeta function-$\ds{\zeta}$ identity](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2.E8).